# mySql order by query by Year and Month name

Tags: php, mysql, date

I want get the table rows order by date(year, month and date)

[image: table]

- if date is blank it should come first
- if date is present then it should be according to date in decreasing order.
- if two rows has same date then second row come first.

How to make it done through mySql query

Comment: [Use ORDER BY to sort on multiple columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html). I strongly suggest you consider changing your table to use a datetime column instead of the three-column setup you're using atm. Using a datetime column will make querying by dates much simpler.

Comment: Which is the data type of the columns Month, Year and date? and based on your sample what's the expected resul ?

Comment: *if two rows has same date then second row come first.* it's unclear what it means because in mysql there is no prev and next row, and moreover you have no unique column to order by it

Comment: @JimL Yes you are right by using the dte time field it would become easier but these fields are in old application not created by me.

Comment: @scaisEdge all these are string field i.e. varchar

Comment: @splash58 If two rows have same date then the ordering should be by their ids in decreasing order.

Comment: Please avoid using (VAR)CHAR datatypes from something where the database has proper values. The DB developers had good reasons why they invented those types...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use cast and field

```
select * from my_table 
order by cast(`year` as signed ) desc, 
FIELD('', `month`, 'January', 'Febrary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September' , 'November', 'December')  desc, 
cast(date as signed)  desc, id desc;
```

Comment: Did your measure other condition given in question

Comment: I have added the id in order by for the second row option .. i hope nothings is forgetten ..

Comment: Ok I will test it tomorrow. Now I'm going to sleep. Thanks

Comment: It throws an error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int) DESC, FIELD(`emonth`, 'January', 'Febrary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'' at line 1`

Comment: I have uodate the answer with another casting sintax  .. and be sure of using backticks for word month and year

Comment: I found the solution from here http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/cast.php

Comment: It does not sort the row when the Month, Year, Date fields are blank

Comment: Update your question with the code you  are using now so i can evaluate it ..

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you would like to correct the datamodel and change the three columns to one date column, but you cannot.

So extend the table with a **generated column** holding the date value instead:

```
alter table mytable add mydate date generated always as
  (str_to_date(concat("date", ' ', "month", ' ', "year"), '%d %M %Y')) stored;
```

From that moment on you will always have the date column to work with. It will be automatically filled based on the existing columns. (You could also make this generated column `virtual` instead of `stored`, but read access would be slower.)

Then use this column to order your result rows. As MySQL's `ORDER BY` doesn't support any `NULLS FIRST / NULLS LAST` clause, you need a `CASE WHEN` expression to get nulls first.

```
select *
from mytable
order by case when mydate is null then 1 else 2 end, mydate desc, id desc;
```

Here is the documentation on generated columns: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html.

Comment: You can replace `case when mydate is null then 1 else 2 end` by `mydate is null desc` or `mydate is not null`

Comment: @ebahi: Yes, you are right. I sometimes forget about MySQL's `true=1` / `false=0`. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you should store the month values as numbers then Use an order by at the end of your query.

```
Order by col1, col2, col3
```

Then either `ASC` OR `DESC` depending on what you need

An even better approach would be use one column as a `DATE` type then you could do:

```
Order by YEAR(col_name), MONTH(col_name), DAY(col_name)
```

Comment: Year month and date fields are string so numeric field value will sort but the month field will be sorted alphabetically

Comment: Ah yes good point! :) I will update my answer for a better approach